# Strange happening with DVD drive in fedora

Tags: fedora, dvd

Strange things are happening! The DVD drive installed on my machine is behaving strangely with some discs that have been burned on a university Windows machines. 
[image]
The files were different, but nautilus is showing 4 strange files. There are supposed to be some folders and other files.
Can anybody help me?

Comment: it looks like the disks were burned in an audio format, rather than a data format. can you confirm or deny this in a windows machine?

Comment: I can safely say that it shows DATA files on a windows machine.

Comment: @Ishan: What was the file system used while burning? ISO 9660? UDF? Something else?

Comment: I'm not sure. The University people refuse to tell me anything or let me touch their computer.

Comment: Problem gone. It was a problem with the mounting-unmounting of the dvd drive. I was new to linux, so i could not understand. Thanks for all the efforts you people put into this. Mods plz lock topic